# Cannot disable GUI for FCEUX 2.2.2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, user-interface, emulation, openai-gym

I am trying to run the FCEUX emulator on AWS without graphical rendering so that my machine learning algorithm can train faster. So far I have tried running FCEUX from command line with the following commands:

```
fceux --nogui 1 /home/me/gym/gym/envs/ppaquette_gym_super_mario/roms/super-mario.nes

fceux /home/me/gym/gym/envs/ppaquette_gym_super_mario/roms/super-mario.nes --nogui 1
```

The first line compiles and runs the rom, but the emulator's GUI still shows.

The second line gives the error

```
Starting FCEUX 2.2.2...
Error opening "1"!
```

Currently I am using Ubuntu 16.04, Python 2.7, and FCEUX 2.2.2. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the syntax is `fceux --nogui /path/to/rom` however it won't yield what you want. GUI refers to heavyweight GUI stuff (menus dialogs). The window still appears (from SDL most likely). Your problem can't be solved without revisions to the source code:

1. in sd;/sdl-video.cpp, make BlitScreen() return immediately

Since you've probably made the unwarranted assumption that taking away the screen would also take away the throttling, you're likely to be disappointed by the results of the edit above. Unless you've been turboing by putting a brick on your tab key, you'll also need to:

2. In sdl/input.cpp, you will need to modify "Toggle Throttling" section to have NoWaiting always set to 1, or |=1. (I haven't tested this to confirm it)